# i dont want any spaces between boxes without using font-size property

Tags: html, css

i have been trying to display 3 boxes in a row without any spaces in-between them.

i want to achieve this without using font-size property.

```css
    html,body {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     margin:0;
     }
    #b {
    height:25%;
    width:25%;
    background:lightblue;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
     <div id=b></div>
     <div id=b></div>
     <div id=b></div>
```

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't repeat IDs

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it is working

```css
 html,body {
         height:100%;
         width:100%;
         margin:0;
         }
        #b {
        margin-left:-4px;
        height:25%;
        width:25%;
        background:lightblue;
        display:inline-block;
        }
```

```html
 <div id=b></div>
     <div id=b></div>
     <div id=b></div>
```